# Databind ListView from ArrayList - javafx

Tags: listview, javafx

I have an ArrayList :

```
List<Column> listOfColumns = new ArrayList();
```

How can I bind this list to a listView? It should always show the columns inside this list.

Also, I use

```
    final ObservableList<Columns> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

right now to make the ListView only contain Columns, but a Column is an object which contains a name(string) and an array list, so right now my ListView shows both the name of the column and the content of the array list in the Column. Is there any way to make the ListView only show the name of the column?

[image]

The reason I do it like this, is because then I can use listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), and it returns a column.

Answer (score 2):

Given that `Column` is a POJO with one `String` field and one `ArrayList`, by default what you see in the `ListView` is given by the `toString()` method.

You just need to customize this method to display what you want:

```
private class Column {

    private String name;

    private ArrayList<String> list;

    public Column(String name, ArrayList list) {
        this.name = name;
        this.list = list;
    }

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //return name + list; 
        return name;          
    }
}
```

Anyway, the listener will return a `Column` object if a row is selected. What you print there depends if you're using `toString()` or just accesing the string field:

```
list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
    (observable,oldValue,newValue)->{
        System.out.println("Selected item: " + newValue);
        System.out.println("Selected item: " + newValue.getName());
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.. I have been looking at this for so long that I actually forgot that I had a return name+arrayList.toString() in my overridden toString method! Great :D